# Chrome extension permission for specific site, WITH all it's subdomains and extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i.e. I want extension to give permissions only for specific company sites, like:

```
www.google.co.uk
xyz.google.com
etc...
```

I've tried:

```
"*://*.google.*/"
```

but it chrome gives errors in extensions page, saying:

```
Permission '*://*.google.*/' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.
```

Comment: See [Chrome extension: Run on all google domains and a specific page](//stackoverflow.com/a/18616735)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the 3rd version of the manifest, the host permissions have now changed location, as seen in the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#host-permissions).

It seems that the [current documentation for webRequests](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#manifest) is not yet up to date, so if you do it the old way, the error `Permission [...] is unknown or URL pattern is malformed` will appear.

So now, instead of the **old way**:

```
// Manifest v2
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks",
  "http://www.blogger.com/",
],
"optional_permissions": [
  "*://*/*",
  "unlimitedStorage"
]
```

You need to adopt the **new way**:

```
// Manifest v3
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks"
],
"optional_permissions": [
  "unlimitedStorage"
],
"host_permissions": [
  "http://www.blogger.com/",
  "*://*/*"
],
```

Comment: It requires migration to v3 and does a lot of works, just suits for new extension development.

Comment: @Zheeeng Yes, that's exactly what I wrote in the answer: if you use v3, then you have to change to this answer. 
If you have an old extension (before v3), then what is written in the current documentation is already enough, and you won't come across this question/answer because you won't have any issues...